# Youngs modulus in ASTM specification A36

Tags: elastic-modulus

In ASTM A36 I cannot find a single mention of the Youngs modulus of the material. It does mention the tensile strength and yield point among other things. Where is such information normally indicated in ASTM specifications?

[image]

Comment: Elastic properties for all structural steels are pretty much the same. E = 200-210 GPa, It probably isn't in the ASTM spec because it isn't a critical parameter like minimum tensile strength etc. You don't *select* a grade of steel based on its Young's modulus.

Comment: @alephzero I agree with you on the range of E but there should be some definite mention of this in ASTM documents or at least the strain at yield. The Youngs modulus,  is definitely an important parameter when it comes to structural design so I do not agree with you on how you define a critical parameter.

Comment: Unless it is high strength steel ( 100,000 psi yield ) the strain at yield is about 0.5 % = 0.2 % offset.

Comment: The font and the use of "yield point" suggests this is an old version, the current A 36 is 19 ( issued 2019). I am sure it will not have the modulus either.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Firstly, the snapshot is from the latest issue and secondly to extract the yield point using the 0.5%/0.2% offset method is impossible unless the coordinate data of the stress-strain curve is available which it is not. Please tell me if I have missed something.

Comment: Yield point is a characteristic of lower carbon, lower strength, hot rolled products ; cold rolled and heat-treated steels do not have yield points . That is why specifications use yield strength. The only way to find a yield point is to pull a test bar; it can not be constructed with certainty.  A specification defines minimum ( and maximum ) properties , it does not indicate actual properties. I suggest you read  definitions of yield point and yield strength.

Comment: @blacksmith37 that is exactly my point where is the minimum specified? If it is not specified, why doesn't ASTM not show it. If they leave it to the manufacturer then where is the clause specifying it is so. Forget A36, can you point me to any other ASTM that specifies the value or clause related to it.

Comment: I have found out I was wrong; ASTM has gone back to yield POINT for some specs.  So the minimum yield point is in your Table 2  = 36,000 psi.

Answer (score 0):

It is steel ; 30 million psi. I don't think I ever saw an ASTM spec with a modulus when I was on A 1 committee. Maybe for castirons as the modulus for them is variable.

Comment: Sorry I do not know what an A1 committee is. Could you elaborate. And I think just because the modulus is variable does not mean it should not be indicated or referenced in some other ASTM specification. I thought the whole purpose of ASTM spec is to standardize the material and its properties when used for different applications.

Comment: A 1 is the ASTM steel committee , writes all the steel specs . Divided into about 15 sections ,such as plate, pipe, tube, castings, forgings and fittings,  etc.  I see now it is not obvious to a casual user of ASTM specs.

Comment: My mistake......

Comment: Or , from another perspective I voted to approve A36 twice as an ASTM spec ( every 5 years).

Answer (score 0):

The information below is provided to echo Alephzero's comment.

[image]

[image]

The mechanical properties can be found easily on the web.

[image]